# How are styles mapped to numbers in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I was working on a mobile application using React Native.

I created small set of styles using `ReactNative.StyleSheet` and use them in my components.

Now i witnessed something peculiar here. I see that that my styles are mapped to some number. Ideally i was expecting an object to be present when I tried printing the style.

Following is my css:-

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex:1,
    alignItems:'center',
    width: null,
  },
  logo: {
    width:110,
    marginTop:84,
    resizeMode:'contain'
  },
  mascot:{
    width:145,
    height:150,
    marginTop:73,
    resizeMode:'contain'
  },
  button:{
    backgroundColor:'#4A90E2',
    width:300,
    alignSelf:'center',
  },
  buttonContainer:{
    marginTop:70
  }
})
```

and `console.log(style)` shows me following. I am trying to understand what are these numbers?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The idea of `StyleSheet.create` is to reduce the number of times the stylesheet object is created to one. Since the object will always have the same values, it makes sense to do that and it is a very simple way of saving some processing time. The number that you get is simply a reference to the created StyleSheet object.

Something similar happens with static images as well. If you `console.log` the value of `require('./myImage.png')`, you will also get a number. Again, for the same optimization reasons.

Comment: Am I the only one that thinks this should be better documented? I have propType validation on my components, and this confused the heck out of me and I wasted some time trying to debug this "problem".

Comment: @RyanPfister Here here. Same thing happened to me. Was validating my PropType as an object but a number was being passed in. Couldn't figure this out until I read this and another post. Not a good developer experience.

Answer (score 1):

I have similar situation for Platform.select function.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    web: {
        width: '50%',
    },
    android: {
        width: '100%',
    }
});


console.log(
    Platform.select({
        web: styles.web,
        android: styles.android
    })
)
```

On android result of console.log is valid object with styles, but in web is reference number. Even if I used this directly in component style, for web styles are not apply correctly, eg.

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{Platform.select({
                web: styles.saveTouchableWeb,
                android: styles.saveTouchableAndroid
            })
        }} .....
```

I found that solution for this can be StyleSheet.flatten but maybe there is better way or practice to solve it?

```
Platform.select({
    web: StyleSheet.flatten(styles.web),
    android: styles.android
})
```

Comment: `StyleSheet.flatten` is the reverse method to get style object from the number value. Thanks for that, it's what I needed.